# Submitting a significant number of apps to the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

I am working on a mobile iOS app that is customized to each client, with their own app icon, startup screen, and a few other changes. Each is then submitted to the app store as an individual app.

This is working just fine so far, but what will happen if there's 1000 clients instead of around a dozen? Does Apple have any rules on quantity, submission rate or uniqueness? Any reviewer would clearly see that the apps are basically the same outside of the branding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it. You will get kicked out of the appstore.

Read 2.20 of Apple iOS Guidelines which says that developers that spam appstore with similar apps will be kicked out completely!

Notably developers like AppGratis got kicked for this and many others reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry can't disclose, if you have a developers account though you can check the requirements
from https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Comment: The information provided is not supposed to be public.. it is offered under NDA via the iOS Developer Program which is why you find it behind a login screen.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but somehow it popped up and the answer selected is not entirely correct. The requester needs the custom B2B program here:

https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/

That is specifically made for the purpose she/he asked about: to distribute customized apps to a business without cluttering the app store. There is no cost but your customers will need to join the Apple Volume Purchase Program for Business though that doesn't cost them anything.

The reason I say the accepted answer is partially correct is because obviously one should not spam up the app store with similar apps intended for one business, which is entirely correct. But that does not answer the underlying why they wanted to do this and how they could achieve the result they need which is to use the B2B program.